# PHP error: Insert record values change

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, undefined, dreamweaver

I am a complete newbie and I am trying to connect Dreamweaver (CS6) with my database in PHPmyAdmin. I have created a page which is supposed to accept values and add it into my database. There are about 10 fields from which I am trying to accept data. I use the insert record key from server behaviors and connect the values in my form to the database but after I connect them all properly and then press ok, it accepts all my entries but then some of them changes automatically when i look and says "does not get a value". 
eg: I am setting 'Techniques Used' gets value from 'FORM.Techniques used' as 'Text'
I click ok and it automatically changes to 'Techniques Used' does not get a value. Finally when i try to add data, it gives the error "PHP error: Notice: Undefined index:". please ask if you need any additional info. This problem is confusing and irritating.

```
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO mirna (Title, Authors, `Year`, Publisher,        Species, Aim, `Techniques Used`, Samples, Disease, Targets, Descriptions, Results,    Discussion, Evidence) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Authors'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Year'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Publisher'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Species'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Aim'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Techniques Used'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Samples'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Disease'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Targets'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Results'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Discussion'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Evidence'], "text"));

    mysql_select_db($database_miRNA, $miRNA);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $miRNA) or die(mysql_error());

    $insertGoTo = "manage_post.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>
```

This is part of the code. Thx. This is what i get when I try to submit data.
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: Techniques Used in C:\wamp\www\PHP\add_post.php on line 48

a bunch of them on different lines...

Comment: Post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: This is not error, its just notice. Use `isset()` to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue myself.. seems that sometimes spaces between words and symbols like / between words can lead to the insert record function to malfunction. Instead of spaces between words in the database, i substituted _ and things seemed to correct itself..